# Access superclass fields

Tags: java, inheritance

For example I have abstract class `Shape`, that gets the coordinates of the shape:

```
public abstract class Shape{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Shape(int x, int y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y
    }

    public abstract void onDraw();

}
```

Now I have the class `Rect` the extends from `Shape`:

```
public class Rect extends Shape{
    private int height;
    private int width;

    public Rect(int height, int width){
        this.height=height;
        this.width=width;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(){
        //this method should get the width and height and the coordinates x and y, and will print the shape rect
    }
}
```

Now my question is: how can I get the coordinates x and y of the abstract class `Shape` from within `Rect`?

Comment: please follow the naming conventions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get them as long as they are `private`. make them `protected` instead.

More information can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Comment: Also the constructor for class rect should be called rect(), not shape().

Comment: Or make getter methods for them...

Comment: Making getters/setters in the abstract class will make the variables accessable in every other subclass, what he might not want. Ig he only needs `x` and `y` in `onDraw()` then making getters in not necessary.

Answer (score 6):

simply make some getters for them:

```
public abstract class shape{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public shape(int x,int y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y
    }

    public abstract void onDraw();

    }

    public int getX() {
        return this. x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return this. y;
    }
```

or make the attributes protected.

**note that x and y will never be set if you create a `rect` because you are not calling the super constructor**

Comment: The original example just wont compile...

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The whole point of it being *private* is that you can't get at the variable. If the class hasn't given any way of finding it out, you can't get it.